# The differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} +y^2 + \frac{x}{1-x}y = \frac{1}{1-x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am learning how to solve differential equations and making some progress. However, how can one solve this example? The task is to find the solution to the equation

$$\frac{dy}{dx} +y^2 + \frac{x}{1-x}y = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

that satisfies $y=2$ at $x=0$.

Comment: This is called a Ricatti Equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the change of variables $y=1+\frac{1}{u(x)}$, the equation then becomes *linear*:
$$u'=\frac{x-2}{x-1}u+1.$$
I think you can take it from here.